# Scala returning List[Int] when calling .head on list

Tags: list, scala, option-type

I'm trying to get the head element of a list, then returning the value as an option. When I use `list.headOption` I get a type mismatch error, saying that `list.headOption` returns `found: Option[List[Int]] required: Option[Int]`

Here's the function:

```
def valueAt(row: Int, col: Int): Option[Int] = {
    val res = available.get((row, col))
    print(res)
    if (res.size == 1){
      res.headOption
    } else {
    None
  }
  }
```

I've also tried replacing `res.headOption` with `Some(res.head)` and I get the same error. I'm honestly lost because I've learned that `.head` returns the first element of the list.

Comment: What's the type of `available.get((row, col))` ? I bet it's a `List[List[Int]]`, try annotating `res`.

Comment: We need compilable code to answer this question. There's not enough information here to know what the types are.

Answer (score 1):

probably `available.get((row, col))` it's returning a `List[List[Int]]`. In this case, the first element will be a `List[Int]`, or a `Option[List[Int]]` of you use `.headOption`

You can convert from `List[List[Int]]` to `List[Int]` doing `res.flatten`, but you should probably change the return type of  `available.get((row, col))`